# How to add dark mode option in customizer in Wordpress theme? (Without plugin)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I developed a wordpress theme. I want to add dark mode option in the customizer. I want to make this choice with the combobox.
When dark mode is selected, it is enough to add a class named dark in the body element. Likewise, when the light mode is selected, it is enough to add the light class named in the body element. How can I do that? (I can do the rest with css.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, I think you're saying that you're using a plugins to handle the darkmode or nightmode but i'm unssure... Using a plugin to handle the nightmode is unnecessary.

Putting in place, a nightmode is fairly simple, we want to add a css class (let's call that class `.night`) to our body tag. Upon a user click we want to toggle 2 differents states. Our current toggle state need to be saved as a `LocalStorage` item. Once this is done, we will define appropriate colors for each sections, div, and any other content in our css. to Let's get started.

Most of the theme are using `jQuery` (a JS library), it will be the only requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    null != localStorage.getItem("state") && (localStorage.settingNight, $("body").toggleClass("night"), $("#toggle").toggleClass("selected")),
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
            $("body").toggleClass("night"), $("#toggle").toggleClass("selected"), $("#toggle").hasClass("selected") ? localStorage.setItem("state", "true") : localStorage.removeItem("state");
        });
});
```

**Here we define multiple css classes and ids:**

- `#toggle`, This is our button. Together with the `.selected` class, they're defining the `LocalStorage` state item.
- `.night`, we use the `.night` css class to apply our appropriate colors for each sections, div, and any other content.
- '.selected', we use the '.selected' css class to know which state we are in. We can also apply a custom style to our `#toggle` button.

**In our `html` we can now add the following:**

```
<button id="toggle">Nightmode</button>
```

This is our toggle button, upon receiving the user click, it will switch state.

**And in our css we can customize the appropriate colors:**

```
.selected{background-color:#f17d3b!important;border-color:#f17d3b!important;}
body.night,
body.night html{background-color:#1d1e22!important;}
```

Here we define our colors for each sections, divs, text ...etc. We use `body.night .class` to target our classes behaviours when the night state is selected.

Finally, I've made a simple codpen with a working example for you to get you started more easily! In this example i'm using the Bootstrap framework, which is unnecessary.
*Source @ https://codepen.io/amarinediary/pen/poErgVw*
Thanks to `LocalStorage`, our browser remembers the night state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this method, any user can switch to dark mode. This is not exactly what I want.
I want to do this (without using plugins) in admin panel on customize page. In other words, the site owner should do this, not the user.
How to do it using $ wp_customize-> add_section and $ wp_customize-> add_setting commands?
If I can't do what I want, I'll use your method. Thanks again.

Comment: One way could be to have one `main.css` stylesheet and 2 other ones `day.css` and `night.css`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it works for me.
To add options to customize page in administration panel:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'theme_mode',
    array(
        'default'     => 'light',
        'type'        => 'theme_mod',
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'mytheme_sanitize_select',
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'theme_mode',
    array(
        'description' => __( 'Choose the theme mode', 'mytheme' ),
        'settings'    => 'theme_mode',
        'section'     => 'mytheme_general_theme_settings',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'priority'    => 10,
        'choices'     => array(
            'light'     => 'Light',
            'dark'      => 'Dark',
        ),
    )
);
```

When Dark Mode is selected from the management panel, to add a class to the body (in functions.php):

```
function mytheme_dark_mode( $classes ) {
    if ( ( get_theme_mod( 'theme_mode', 'dark' ) === 'dark' ) ) { 
    $classes[] = 'dark-theme';
        return $classes;    
    }
    else{
        return $classes;
    }
}
add_filter( 'body_class','mytheme_dark_mode' );
```

If there is an error in the code, I would appreciate it if you fix it.